# Cross referencing in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markup

in Jupyter notebook, is it possible to cross-reference a heading number in the markup cell.

For example, I have a paragraph like  " As explained in Section 1.1... "

1.1 is a heading number. If I insert another heading above heading 1.1 , then the cross-reference should automatically change to 1.2 , like what happens in MS word